# tcolorbox tcbhighmath box customization

Tags: tcolorbox, empheq

I am making some lecture notes for myself and I would like to use this feature to put important equations in boxes. However I am only able to do this one type of box showed in the sample code and I would like to be able to customize the boxes with the followig features:

- Changing the thickness and color of the frame.
- Changing the shape of the corners sharp/round.
- Changing the color of the backgound.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box=\tcbhighmath]{align*}
a&=\sin(z)\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^b x\, dx
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

I took a look at the documentation but I was not able to find simple examples from which to extract the patterns I am looking for, the explanations I found there were general considerations about the design of the package and it rather hard to understand for someone like me with just the basic working knowledge on LaTeX. I would appreciate if anyone can tell me how to customize this box.

Kind regards and thanks you in advance.

Comment: The manual is full of examples. Are you sure you looked at the right document? Just look through until you find an example you like and copy the code. Look under the 'skins' sections for examples, maybe, rather than starting at the beginning.

Comment: If you search the manual for `\tcbhighmath` you literally find examples of ways to vary this box and/or create boxes which behave in the same way. The first example shows you how to do at least 2 of the 3 things you're asking about.

Comment: @cfr I looked at this document: https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf

Comment: The examples that appear there are not minimal and so are not very useful to me as they are mixed with another parts of code that I do not intend to use at all.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so after a further review at the documentation and some trial and error I managed to do what I wanted. I will just post the code as it is self-explanatory. I am sorry that I am not able to provide further detail on why the code is the way it is or how the package is structure. So this is just a very simple answer to a very particular question. Hope someone else can benefit from this.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\newtcbox{\boxgreen}[1][]{% tcolorbox manual 375
  notitle, 
  nophantom,
  nobeforeafter,
  math upper,
  colframe=green, 
  sharp corners,
  colback=yellow!25!white,
  #1,
}
\newtcbox{\boxblue}[1][]{% tcolorbox manual 375
  notitle, 
  nophantom,
  nobeforeafter,
  math upper,
  colframe=blue, 
  sharp corners,
  colback=blue!10!white,
  #1,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box=\tcbhighmath]{align*}
a&=\sin(z)\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^b x\, dx
\end{empheq}

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{empheq}[box=\boxgreen]{align*}
a&=\sin(z)\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^b x\, dx
\end{empheq}

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{empheq}[box=\boxblue]{align*}
a&=\sin(z)\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^b x\, dx
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image: three box styles]

Comment: I tried to add a picture of the output, but I get errors when I try to compile this code. Does it work for you?

Comment: Please see edit. I think you need `nobeforeafter,math upper`. (At least you need `nobeforeafter`.) I also added `#1` so you can use the optional argument, if you wish, and a picture of the output.

Comment: @cfr Yes indeed, better this way, as now there is no compiling errors. Thank you!